# Find the number of times $5$ will be written while listing integers from $1$ to $1000$

Tags: combinatorics

Just a question and then, I'll come up with my doubt. It will be easier to explain then.

> **Question:** Find the number of times $5$ will be written while listing integers from $1$ to $1000$.

Now, it can be solved in this fashion. The numbers will be of the form: $5xy, x5y, xy5$ where $x,y$ denote the two other digits such that $0\leq x,y \leq 9$. So, $x,y$ can take $10$ choice each. So, answer is $10^2$ multiplied by $3$ for the $3$ sets of numbers mentioned. Answer becomes $300$ and it's correct.

But the thing is: When we are considering $x5y$, we include $557$ in this. Again, we include $557$ while considering $5xy$, right? 
So that's a double count, yet the answer is right? This way I think there'll be a lot of *more-than 1 counts*, I'm not sure.

Please explain me. Regards

Comment: The hightligted question is hard to understand -- I recognize each word as being English, but they don't seem to combine into a sentence I can parse.

Comment: 557 is counted twice, but then it has two fives, so that is correct.

Comment: Yeah, got that. Thanks.

Comment: When you are "considering $x5y$" you are only looking at and counting the $5$ in the middle. Before you were considering $5xy$, and later you will be considering $xy5$ in the same way. – Things would be different if the problem were: "How many numbers between $1$ and $1000$ contain a digit $5$?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By adding the number of times the digit $5$ occurs in each position, you have counted each number in which $5$ appears exactly two times twice and each number in which $5$ appears exactly three times thrice, once for each position in which it occurs, which is why your method produces the right answer.

**Alternate Method:**  We want to count the number of times the digit $5$ appears in the list of positive integers from $1$ to $1000$.  Thus, we need to count each integer in which the digit $5$ appears exactly once once, each integer in which the digit $5$ appears exactly two times twice, and each integer in which the digit $5$ appears exactly three times thrice.

*Numbers in which the digit $5$ appears exactly once*:  There are three ways to choose the position of the digit $5$.  Since we cannot use $5$ in the remaining positions, there are nine choices for each of the remaining digits.  Hence, there are 
$$\binom{3}{1}9^2$$
such numbers.

*Numbers in which the digit $5$ appears exactly twice*:  There are $\binom{3}{2}$ ways to choose the positions of the digit $5$.  Since we cannot use $5$ in the remaining position, there are nine choices for the remaining digit.  Hence, there are 
$$\binom{3}{2}9$$
such numbers.

*Numbers in which the digit $5$ appears exactly thrice*:  There is only one such number, namely $555$.

*Total*:  The number of times the digit $5$ appears when listing each integer from $1$ to $1000$ is 
$$\binom{3}{1}9^2 + 2\binom{3}{2}9 + 3\binom{3}{3} = 243 + 54 + 3 = 300$$

Answer (score 5):

From $0$ to $999$ there are $1000$ numbers and they have $10\times 1+90\times 2+900\times 3=2890$ digits

$190$ are zeros and the other $2700$ are divided equally between the other digits, so there are $300$ fives as $300$ nines etc

Comment: +1, if we write them down as with leading zeroes as three digit numbers then we have 3000 digits and 3000/10=300 is the number of appearances of each of the digits form 0 to 9